# How do I install cuda on jetson nano ARM hardware without USB?

Tags: apt, nvidia, dpkg, cuda

I don't have physical access to jetson nano machine, but I want to install DeepStream. It fails because of dependencies:

```
root@nvidia-desktop:~# dpkg -i deepstream-4.0_4.0-1_arm64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package deepstream-4.0.
(Reading database ... 118956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack deepstream-4.0_4.0-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking deepstream-4.0 (4.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of deepstream-4.0:
 deepstream-4.0 depends on cuda-cudart-10-0; however:
  Package cuda-cudart-10-0 is not installed.
 deepstream-4.0 depends on cuda-cudart-dev-10-0; however:
  Package cuda-cudart-dev-10-0 is not installed.
 deepstream-4.0 depends on cuda-npp-10-0; however:
  Package cuda-npp-10-0 is not installed.
 deepstream-4.0 depends on cuda-npp-dev-10-0; however:
  Package cuda-npp-dev-10-0 is not installed.
 deepstream-4.0 depends on libnvinfer5 (>= 5.1.2); however:
  Package libnvinfer5 is not installed.
 deepstream-4.0 depends on libnvinfer-dev (>= 5.1.2); however:
  Package libnvinfer-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package deepstream-4.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 deepstream-4.0
```

How can I install these dependencies without **sdkmanager**, which requires direct access to device via USB? I tried to find cuda for arm64, but on nvidia website there is no way to download them, only amd64. Are there public repositories with **cuda-cudart-10-0**, **libnvinfer5** and the rest of it.

Comment: http://developer.nvidia.com/accelerated-computing-toolkit

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia read carefully the answer, your link has no ARM binaries for CUDA. (Or show me if it does.)

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032497/cuda-setup-and-installation/install-cuda-9-on-arm64/

Comment: Read the question carefully. JetPack requires connecting USB cable.

Comment: I see no answer, there is some discussion regarding cuda 9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97504/discussion-between-stiv-and-gabrielagarcia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people encountered alike problems while installing with **sdkmanager**. But if you flash lastest image, which has some fixes, then all software is already installable with **apt-get**.